# Pie chart won't display

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts, pie-chart

I'm trying to create a pie chart where the top 10 books from my "book" table are shown (I'm doing a library system).

I have worked out how many times each book in the top 10 has been loaned out by a borrower in a loop, and have also worked out the percentage and degrees for each book to form the pie chart, however I cannot seem to find a way to actually form the pie chart itself.

I also can't figure out how to make the percentage into an array so that in the second loop, it will display the arc for each book.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) FROM loan GROUP BY book_id ASC ORDER BY         count(*) DESC LIMIT 10");
    $book_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $step = 1;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $total = $total + $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $i[$step] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    $step++;
    }

    $pie = imagecreate(500,500);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($pie,255,255,255);
    imagefill($pie,0,0,$white);

    $font = imageloadfont('calibri.gdf');
    $black = imagecolorallocate($pie,0,0,0);  //This is for the labeling also

    $angle = 0;

    for($index = 1; $index <= 10; $index++)
    {
        $percentage = (($i[$index]/$total)*100);
        #$degrees = (($percentage/100)*360);
    }

    for ($index2=0, $count=count($percentage); $index2<$count; $index2++)
    {
        #$percentage = (($i[$index]/$total)*100);
        $degrees = (($percentage[$index]/100)*360);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($pie,mt_rand(20,255),mt_rand(20,255),mt_rand(20,255));

        imagefilledarc($pie,100,100,125,125,$angle,($angle+$degrees),$color,IMG_ARC_PIE);
        imagefilledrectangle($pie,250,(50+(25*($index2+1))),275,(75+(25*($index2+1))),$color);
        imagestring($pie,$font,276,(55+(25*($index2+1))),$percentage[$index2]."  %",$black);

        $angle+=$degrees;
    }

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($pie);
    imagedestroy($pie);

    #echo "<br>";
    #echo 'The sum is: ' . $total;

?>
```

Comment: I think we need more information.  If you echo $pie is there any data in it?

Comment: @mcassano Nope, that's what seems to be the problem, the info I have from my query and other information I've worked out doesn't gel with $pie.